# Android: How to run/debug/test android app on tab?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

I'm a novice in android app development (using Android Studio) and want to make an app and all set for go on but I have an issue and that is how can I run my app on my tab for test purpose as you know android emulator is slow (very slow). I had checked some answer but all are for window specific and I have Linux operating system.

- I have a tablet (not rooted).
- Usb cable.
- wifi connection.

I need a way where I don't have to root my tablet and work on Linux too.

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Comment: you are amazing Mark, helping even people that just start or that are not under warescription. you really gotta love android! Really a genuine advocate of this marvellous OS!

Comment: You don't have to root your device to develop with it. Follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#setting-up) to set up your device and development machine. Pay particular attention to the steps for Linux. Even though the docs explicitly mention Ubuntu, the steps are usually the same for other Linux distros. If you encounter problems along the way, please come back with more questions after researching the problem on your own. Be sure to include sufficient details so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the cable of the tablet, linux should recognize it, if is not recognized you may install a driver.You can run the command:

> $ lsusb

After that when appears the screen after you press run in AS, just select the device instead of the emulator.
If does not work, it could be that your tablet in development options ( psychically you have to interact with your tablet) does not have checked the option debug( on default is not activated), on some devices you have to look in the internet how to access to this option.
A last recommendation is to check in the manifest and in the build.gradle( take care there are two of them) that debbugable is set as true